# How do I make my app scale properly on 13-inch iOS tablets?

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad

We finally got a 12.9-inch iPad Pro in the office! However, when putting our app on it, it's just stretched to fit the screen. Looking at the project file, I don't see any settings that would change this. **How do I make our app properly scale on these large iPads?**

---

I already tried Googling this, but I keep getting reviews and people begging for Xcode on iOS:

- [How do i make my app work on iPad Pro?](https://www.google.com/#safe=active&q=How+do+i+make+my+app+work+on+iPad+Pro%3F)
- [Make Xcode project iPad Pro compatible](https://www.google.com/#safe=active&q=Make+Xcode+project+iPad+Pro+compatible)
- [iPad Pro .xcodeproj](https://www.google.com/#safe=active&q=iPad+Pro+.xcodeproj)
- [Making your app work in iPad Pro](https://www.google.com/#safe=active&q=Making+your+app+work+in+iPad+Pro)
- [How to optimize app for iPad Pro](https://www.google.com/#safe=active&q=How+to+optimize+app+for+iPad+Pro)
- etc.

Comment: Are you using a launch storyboard?

Comment: @dan No, but we have a main nib file

Comment: Using `Autolayout` properly makes your app work perfectly on iPad Pro as well.

Comment: What do you mean by "stretched"? Is your app a universal app? What do you get for the `bounds` on the `UIScreen mainScreen` in `application: didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`. ?

Comment: @rmaddy I mean it's literally stretched, like a wallpaper that's too small for its monitor. Compare [these screenshots wherein my app's status bar is clearly stretched as compared to that of the Settings app](https://photos.google.com/share/AF1QipOaFY2TGGYVr2Qu8fyVONjYg_PHfagVHOtVu0YJxq0L14CAqZTA9bTFJiuU3Qo3Sg?key=QzIxSW4wOEdVRWxwQThNV3pOWmJEenZkZUVpMk5R). It is a universal app, yes; it works fine on iPod, iPhone, iPad, iPad Air, and iPad Mini. As for your third question: `(origin = (x = 0, y = 0), size = (width = 1024, height = 768))`

Comment: That means your app thinks it is on a regular iPad when running on the iPad Pro. That probably means you don't actually have a proper Launch screen file in place. I know you stated that you do but your app doesn't seem to believe you. Update your question with a screenshot or two showing how you have the launch screen file setup.

Answer (score 1):

If you build with the iOS 9 SDK, then your app is expected to support all resolutions. Same if you use iOS 8 SDK and use a launch storyboard. Without that, iOS assumes that you don't support the resolution, but scales an iPad app. So that's what you need to do: iOS 9 SDK, and/or launch storyboard.

Comment: What if we use iOS 9 SDK but Deployment Target 7.1?

Comment: @BenC.R.Leggiero Deployment Target is irrelevant. The requirement to support the iPad Pro is the use of a Launch Screen File. That's it.

Comment: @rmaddy well, then that's weird. We have a launch screen file, and we're using iOS 9 SDK,  but our app is still being stretched to fit this 12.9-inch iPad Pro. :/